# Class member variable are dynamic. Depending upon the keys of a map in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a map in typescript like
myMap : Map = new Map();

myMap having some keys & values

I am iterating the map like below

```
for(let [key, value] of this.myMap) {
   ///some code which can create a class whose member variable will be the key of the map and the values of the member variables will be the values of the keys
}
```

e.g if keys of map are ==> apple, mango etc
    if corresponding values are 1, 2 
then create dynamically while iterating the map

```
myClass {
  apple = 1;
  mango = 2;
}
```

Comment: Looks like no ask or question here... What do you want, filter a Map object?

Comment: I want to create a class using the keys of map as member variable & default values will be the value of the corresponding key of the map

Comment: How many classes will be create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
let myClass = {};
for (const [key, value] of this.myMap.entries()) {
  myClass = {
    ...myClass,
    [key]: value,
  }
}
```

Comment: My Map is defined like below:    myMap : Map<any, any> = new Map()     So it is giving error that property reduce is not available on type Map<any, any>

Comment: ahhh, I got it, I have updated my answer, please check